# I want to do an autocomplete with Ruby and Sequel

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I am using Sequel with prostgres and Sinatra. I want to do an autocomplete search. I’ve verified my jQuery which sends a GET works fine.

The Ruby code is:

```
get '/search' do
  search = params[:search]
  DB[:candidates].select(:last).where('last LIKE ?', '_a_').each do |row|
    l = row[:last] 
  end
end
```

The problem is the Sequel query:

I have tried every possible configuration of the query that I can think of with no luck.

So, for example, in the above query I get all the people who have "a" in their last name but when I change the query to:

```
DB[:candidates].select(:last).where('last LIKE ?', 'search')
```

or

```
DB[:candidates].select(:last).where('last LIKE ?', search)  # (without '')
```

I get nothing.

I have done `warn params.inspect` which indicates the param search is being passed, so I am stuck.

Any ideas how the query should be written?

Finally, the second part of the question the results (when it works with `'_a_'`) are rendered as `{:last=>"Yao"}` I would like just Yao, how can I do that?

I have tried numerous different types of query including raw SQL but no luck. Or is the approach just plain wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `...where('last LIKE ?%', 'search')` ?

Comment: Looks very promising. I tried and this is hwat I got: {"search"=>"y"}
Sequel::DatabaseError - PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: SELECT "last" FROM "candidates" WHERE (last LIKE %'search')

Comment: You should put % inside quotes. Search string should be like `'search%'` which mean you are looking for everything started with `search`...

Comment: I tried this where('last LIKE ?', 'search%') and nothing happens, no query is executed. I tried where('last LIKE %?', 'search%') and got an error. We are almost there but not quite.

Comment: Maybe you should also change `last` and `where`, I mean `where` should be first in sentence. BTW, why do you need `last`?

Comment: last is the column name, not "last" in the sense of first or last. Maybe that's a problem!

Comment: Don't know. I'm not a pro in Postresql. Sorry )

Comment: thanks anyway. I think it' a sequel thing not a postgres thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy/pasting from [the Sequel documentation](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/dataset_filtering_rdoc.html):

> You can search SQL strings in a case sensitive manner using the `Sequel.like` method:
>
> ```
> items.where(Sequel.like(:name, 'Acme%')).sql
> #=> "SELECT * FROM items WHERE (name LIKE 'Acme%')"
> ```
>
> You can search SQL strings in a case insensitive manner using the `Sequel.ilike` method:
>
> ```
> items.where(Sequel.ilike(:name, 'Acme%')).sql
> #=> "SELECT * FROM items WHERE (name ILIKE 'Acme%')"
> ```
>
> You can specify a Regexp as a like argument, but this will probably only work on PostgreSQL and MySQL:
>
> ```
> items.where(Sequel.like(:name, /Acme.*/)).sql
> #=> "SELECT * FROM items WHERE (name ~ 'Acme.*')"
> ```
>
> Like can also take more than one argument:
>
> ```
> items.where(Sequel.like(:name, 'Acme%', /Beta.*/)).sql
> #=> "SELECT * FROM items WHERE ((name LIKE 'Acme%') OR (name ~ 'Beta.*'))"
> ```

[Open up a Sequel console](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/bin_sequel_rdoc.html) (not your Sinatra app) and play with the query until you get results back. Since you say you want only the `last` column your query should be something like:

```
# Search anywhere inside the last name
DB[:candidates].where( Sequel.ilike(:last, "%#{search}%") ).select_map(:last)

# Find last names starting with the search string
DB[:candidates].where( Sequel.ilike(:last, "#{search}%") ).select_map(:last)
```

Uglier alternatives:

```
DB[:candidates]
  .select(:last)
  .where( Sequel.ilike(:last, "%#{search}%") )
  .all
  .map{ |hash| hash[:last] }

DB[:candidates]
  .select(:last)
  .where( Sequel.ilike(:last, "%#{search}%") )
  .map( :last )
```

---

If you want to rank the search results by the best matches, you *might* be interested in my free [LiqrrdMetal library](https://github.com/Phrogz/liqrrdmetal). Instead of searching on the DB, you would pull a full list of all last names into Ruby and use LiqrrdMetal to search through them. This would allow a search string of "pho" to match both "Phong" as well as "Phrogz", with the former scoring higher in the rankings.

Comment: whoopee! I was waiting for you to show up Phrogz, nice one. This works great: DB[:candidates].where( Sequel.ilike(:last, "%#{search}%") ).select_map(:last)
Thanks you too everybody who has given thought to this, I am very grateful. JUst one more, if I may. In PHP the results would be broken up by \n, ho can I have each returned name be on a different line? Thank you!

Comment: P.S. I will check out LiqrrdMetal.

Comment: `.join("\n")` to turn the array into a single newline-delimited string.

Answer (score 1):

Just installed `Sequel` and made working example:

```
require "rubygems"
require "sequel"

# connect to an in-memory database
DB = Sequel.sqlite

# create an items table
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  Float :price
end

# create a dataset from the items table
items = DB[:items]

# populate the table
items.insert(:name => 'abc', :price => rand * 100)
items.insert(:name => 'def', :price => rand * 100)
items.insert(:name => 'ghi', :price => rand * 100)
items.insert(:name => 'gui', :price => rand * 100)

# print out the number of records
puts "Item count: #{items.count}"

# print out the average price
puts "The average price is: #{items.avg(:price)}"

recs = items.select(:name).where(Sequel.like(:name, 'g%'))
recs.each do |rec|
  puts rec.values
end
```

I think you will get the point.

UPDATED

So in your case you should try this:

```
DB[:candidates]
   .select(:last)
   .where(Sequel.like(:last, "#{search}%"))
   .map{|rec| rec.values}.flatten
```

It should return array of found strings.

Comment: thanks, no error but seems query not executed because no output. I copied exactly, just changed filed names. Terminal says: 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2013 21:31:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 28622 7.3856
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2013 21:31:46] "GET /search?search=y HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.3699
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2013 21:31:47] "GET /search?search=ya HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.3733

Comment: thanks, nothing came back? How can I see it or print it anyway? Sorry! Thank you for al the thought you are putting in to this.

Comment: Try to use developer console in browser and watch what were send and resieved